# Where can I find a good JavaScript/HTML AutoSuggest example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a good example implementation of a JavaScript/HTML AutoSuggest input box to get me started. What I am trying to implement will behave "Exactly" like the Tags input box here on stackoverflow.

If it helps I am using jQuery to perform Ajax request.

I am finding examples to help me implement this however I am concerned what about best practices in the area and would love to get opinions also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Er, [jQuery Autocomplete](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html)?  And [another example](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/).

Comment: I am gonna go with jQuery Autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

Antonio Lupetti has just posted a review of Javascript based auto suggest scripts in his article [Useful Ajax Auto Suggest scripts collection](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/02/useful-ajax-auto-suggest-scripts.html).

You might find some interesting links there?

Answer (score 1):

Try the YUI Auto complete. Works great!! http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

I used brandspankingnew's AutoSuggest (and happy of it) -> [http://www.brandspankingnew.net](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/08/ajax_auto-suggest_auto-complete.html)